# C# TimerCallback return value error

Tags: c#

When I use <kbd>F11</kbd> debug, `NetStatus` value is `true`, but when I use <kbd>F5</kbd> debug, `NetStatus` value is `false`. Why? How do I fix it?

I don't know what time the `_connect` value changes.
Is this a multi-threading synchronization issue?

```
namespace conn
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Sockets;
    using System.Threading;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            wait_conn();
        }

        private static void wait_conn()
        {
            bool NetStatus = false;
            string DataS = "127.0.0.1";

            CheckIpConn conn = new CheckIpConn();
            conn.CheckIp(DataS);

            //Thread.Sleep(3000);
            NetStatus = conn.Connected;

            if (!NetStatus)
                Console.WriteLine(conn.Connected.ToString());

            Console.Read();
        }
    }

    public class CheckIpConn
    {
        private int _port = 135;
        private volatile bool _connect;
        private IPEndPoint _iPEndPoint;
        private TcpClient _client;
        private TimerCallback _timerCallBack;
        private System.Threading.Timer _timer;

        public bool Connected
        {
            get { return _connect; }
        }

        public void CheckIp(string Ip)
        {
            _iPEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(Ip), _port);
            _timerCallBack = new TimerCallback(CheckConnect);
            _timer = new System.Threading.Timer(_timerCallBack, null, 10, 1000);
            _timer.Dispose();
        }

        public void CheckConnect(object o)
        {
            try
            {
                _client = new TcpClient();
                _client.Connect(_iPEndPoint);
                _connect = true;
                _client.Close();
            }
            catch
            {
                _connect = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is *extremely* unclear - it looks like you're trying to do things asynchronously, but doing so badly. For example, you're creating a `Timer` and then *immediately* disposing of it.

When stepping line by line in the debugger, that may work - because the timer may get to fire before the `Dispose` call... but when you just run the code, you're disposing of the timer before it gets a chance to fire. Additionally, you're using the value of `conn.Connected` immediately after calling `CheckIp` - so if the timer *did* fire, it would probably be after you'd checked the value anyway.

I would *strongly* advise you to just do the check synchronously. Get that working and *then* consider an asynchronous approach.

Comment: i see! i add Thread.Sleep(300); before conn.Connected, and add Thread.Sleep(2000); before  _timer.Dispose(); now, it is work! thanks you!

Comment: @flyingnn: That's not a good solution though. That's basically a slow and unreliable way of checking the connection... as I said, I would strongly advise using a synchronous approach unless you really want to do the asynchronous approach *properly*. Peppering your code with `Sleep` calls is *not* a good way of getting to a reliable system.

Comment: i am a C# beginner. i want to check the target host network status,before connect to it's SQL port. otherwise , when SQL SERVER down, user will wait  20-30S.

Comment: @flyingnn: But you *are* connecting to that port - you're just giving up after a few seconds.

Comment: public void CheckConnect(object o)? it just is a test connect. if NetStatus value is true, will do SQL connect.

Comment: @flyingnn: That's still trying to connect to the IP address/port you give it - which I assume is the SQL server one. So your claim that "I  want to check the target host network status,before connect to it's SQL port" doesn't really work here, unless you're actually giving it a different address/port.

Answer (score 0):

You create a timer which executes a function on the threadpool - so you don't really have much of a gurantee that when `CheckIP` returns the timer callback has been exececuted.

Furthermore: Why do you dispose of the timer as soon as you created it? While [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zb0225y6.aspx) states that a callback can occur after dispose because the callback is queued this is certainly a bad style. Also this means that you are only checking once - so you might as well do it synchroneously - especially `wait_conn` indicates that it should wait until a connection has been established.

Also: `TcpClient` is disposable so you should do:

```
using (var client = new TcpClient())
{ 
     client.Connect(_iPEndPoint);
     _connect = true;
     client.Close();
}
```

There is no point having a member variable in the class if you do not do anything with it anyway.